# How to determine SQL server version install history? I.E. When it was updated last

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have various SQL server installs across several machines, and a different IT staff will sometimes randomly update each machine with different service packs and cause version issues.

Is there a way to see the version update history for the different SQL machines?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/f3949324-32ce-40fb-bdff-1da540d15538

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try this folder?

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Update Cache
```

I once needed it. And found all the previous setups there. You can check their last modified dates. Maybe it helps.

Comment: This worked for me!  I found a folder created yesterday that explains a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
$server = "ServerName"
$srv = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' $server
$srv | Select Name,product,ProductLevel,ResourceLastUpdateDateTime
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on a SQL Server 2012 server the script just threw an error saying it couldn't find `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server`?